# « Lorsqu'il » et « lorsque Ilona » (prononciation et écriture)

Tags: prononciation, conjonctions, élision

> Lorsqu'il vs lorsque Ilona
>
> Lorsqu'elle vs lorsque Hélène
>
> Lorsqu'on vs lorsque Ondine
>
> Lorsqu'une vs lorsque Ugo
>
> Lorsqu'en vs lorsque Antoine

etc.

Je sais que cette conjonction renonce à son E final devant les pronoms et articles qui commencent par une voyelle. Cependant, y a-t-il des différences quant à la prononciation ?  *Lorsqu'on* et *lorsque Ondine* par exemple.

La seule différence est-elle l'orthographe ? Prononce-t-on /lɔʁskɔ̃/ et /lɔʁskɔ̃din/ ?

Comment: de ce que j'en sais le e devient muet dans ces cas là

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le ***e*** final de *lorsque*, même quand il est présent à l'écrit, n'est pas prononcé devant une voyelle ou un *H* muet, que le mot qui suit soit un nom propre ou pas.

Comme Grevisse et Goose l'autorisent (*Nouvelle grammaire française, 3<sup>e</sup> édition*, 1995):

[image]
je prononce **et** j'écris :

> Lorsqu'Ilona...
>
> Lorsqu'Hélène...

etc., mais le ***e*** de *lorsque* peut (et doit d'après d'autres grammairiens) aussi rester présent dans ces expressions, sans en changer la prononciation.

> Lorsque Ilona...
>
> Lorsque Hélène...

Il faut distinguer l'élision à l'écrit et l'élision à l'oral. Quand elle est écrite, une élision est toujours rendue à l'oral mais le contraire n'est pas systématique.

Par exemple, il y a toujours élision à l'oral dans :

> Ma grand**e** amie

bien que l'on n'écrive pas :

> Ma grand'amie

Comment: Désolé mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre. Je feuillette le livre Optimiser son score au Certificat Voltaire (Éditions Puf, 2016). L'auteur fait bien la différence entre lorsqu'on et lorsque Ondine ; lorsqu'en et lorsque Antoine. Il affirme que la conjonction lorsque renonce à son E final devant les pronoms et articles qui commencent par une voyelle.

Comment: Écris aussi ? Ce n'est certainement pas standard.

Comment: Type de faute à repérer : Lorsqu'Élise a prononcé ces mots au lieu de lorsque Élise ; d'après le livre.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ce qui n'est pas standard, c'est l'avis des grammairiens sur le sujet. Grevisse, qui n'est pas n'importe qui, admet l'élision avec *lorsque* dans tous les cas : Nouvelle grammaire française, *Grevisse et Goosse*, p. 25.

Comment: @dimitris *Puis, lorsqu'Hélène lui donnait la tasse*, Les Rougon-Macquart - Une page d'amour, Émile Zola.

Comment: Alors, le livre dont je parle dit de n'importe quoi, non? Est-ce possible ? C'est un livre pour un concours d'orthographe...

Comment: Même la page web du projet Voltaire fait bien la différence entre lorsqu'elle est arrivée et lorsque Anne est arrivée. Comment est-ce possible un tel écart pour quelque chose assez fondamental ?

Comment: Grevisse est comme la Bible du français, certes. Or, c'est étonnant pour quelqu'un le français n'est pas sa langue maternelle  de voir : http://www.ladictee.fr/grammaire/truc_astuce_grammaire/lorsque_ou_lorsqu.html ou bien https://www.ortholud.com/conjonction-lorsque-1.html

Comment: @jlliagre  On constate qu'il n'y pas d'unanimité dans les livres : http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/lorsqu-a-a103068249 . J'abandonne :-)!

Comment: *Assez fondamental* est un peu exagéré. Je dirais que c'est une règle malheureusement fréquemment prônée qui est difficilement défendable. On doit écrire *pendant qu’Élise arrivait* et pas *pendant que Élise arrivait*, mais à l'inverse on s'interdit *lorsqu'Élise est arrivée* et on impose *lorsque Élise est arrivée*. C'est assez absurde.

Comment: @jlliagre : Alors, Grevisse et toujours Grevisse :-)! La situation est problématique quand même voire folle. Considérons le cas ou un sujet du Certificat Voltaire (un certificat pour ceux qui vont démontrer leur maîtrise de l'orthographe française) comporterait la phrase : Lorsqu'Élise est arrivée...(c'est une variante qui paraît souvent dans des livres concernant ce Certificat). L'étudiant ayant vu Grevisse et l'Académie française dirait que c'est correct et par contre le correcteur attendrait faux:-)!

Comment: Et même le correcteur de Windows ne reconnaît l'élision lorsqu' que pour les cas résumés dans la question.

Answer (score 1):

- *Dans les cas de gauche où il y une apostrophe ( ' )*, les deux mots liés
  par l’apostrophe se lisent comme s'ils étaient *un* seul mot, donc
  attachés lors de la prononciation !
- *En revanche, dans les cas de droite*, ils s'agit de (lorsque + nom propre) **et là on doit bien prononcer le "e" à la fin de chaque 
  "lorsque"** et reprendre le mot propre qui suit en le prononçant lui aussi tout entier. C'est comme pour donner et marquer l'importance de ces
  noms propres !!

Comment: "Lorsque" ne s'élide pas devant d'autres mot que "un", "on", "il(s)" ou "elle(s), mais en pratique, à l'oral, le "e" final sera bien souvent  muet avant tout une autre voyelle.

Answer (score 1):

Je prononcerais /lɔrskilona/, /lɔrskelɛn/ etc. de même qu'on dit /labɛlelɛn/ et pas /labɛləelɛn/.  On peut hésiter entre /lɔrskəɑ̃ri/ et /lɔrskɑ̃ri/ et entre /lorskəygo/ et /lɔrskygo/ pour le poète, étant donné que Henri et Hugo (Victor) sont censés commencer par des *h* muets.

Comment: Il y a, en tout cas en Europe, une assez forte tendance à faire la disjonction avant les prénoms, surtout si ils sont courts. . J'ai aussi repéré dans mon propre usage une tendance à généraliser le schva final de mots comme lorsque, entre ou jusque quand ils apparaissent isolés, ce qui me paraît indicatif d'un changement /ə/ -> /œ/ vers une voyelle stable. Des cas comme /lɔrskəilɔna/ sont sans doute partiellement à rapprocher de ces deux phénomènes, complètement détaché de la présence d'un h aspiré ou des conventions orthographiques de lorsque